# Convert array with random unique numbers to one with sequentially proceeding numbers?

Tags: c#, c, arrays, random, numbers

Let's say I have array which contains unique random numbers (where numbers have small possible range of 0 to 20). For example:

```
[6, 3, 11, 9, 4, 5]
```

How can I convert following array to something like this:

```
[3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 2]
```

The second array starts from 0 and ends with (array.Length-1), but placement is relative to magnitude in the first array.

How can I implement this in an efficient way in C/C++/C#? (more interested in the method)

I gave just one example. It can be really anything:

```
[7, 10, 0, 19, 50, 33, 45, 100]
[1, 2,  0,  3,  6,  4,  5,   7]
```

Smallest number from array A is 0 in array B. Biggest number in array A is (array.Length-1) in array B. Array A can be completely random (just it will never contain two or more identical numbers), but array A have to contain all numbers from 0 to array.Length-1) in same order as in array A.

Comment: How does the conversion work? Is it `A1 - 3`? `A1 / 2`? Please show some attempt to solve it yourself first.

Comment: `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.`

Comment: I just need idea/method how to implement this. I am trying to implement it in C#, but I am sure this is not critical if it is for C, C++ or C#.

Comment: can you give more sample inputs and outputs? what is your first attempt? try using just pen and paper first

Comment: Aha! Do you want the output array to be the position of the input numbers if they were sorted?

Comment: May solution be in Objective C?

Comment: I do not understand the vitriol directed at this question. OP is asking for an algorithm, and the problem seems pretty clear to me. He has demonstrated a "minimal understanding of the problem being solved". I suppose he could add some attempted solution, but I have seen far worse questions.

Comment: Seeing solution in Objective C would be nice too, since I can apply this to any iOS work in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int[] list1 = new[] { 7, 10, 0, 19, 50, 33, 45, 100 };
var orderedList = list1.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
int[] list2 = list1.Select(x => orderedList.IndexOf(x)).ToArray();
```

**EDIT**

Per @Blorgbeard's request

```
int[] list1 = new[] { 6, 3, 11, 9, 4, 5 };

var dict = list1.OrderBy(x => x)
                .Select((i, inx) => new { i, inx })
                .ToDictionary(x => x.i, x => x.inx);

int[] list2 = list1.Select(x => dict[x]).ToArray();
```

Comment: Very nice, +1. As crappy as the question is, the problem is still interesting and this is a pretty awesome solution.

Comment: @tnw no offense to 14V, but it's the obvious solution, and it looks like O(n^2) - I would be interested in whether it could be done more efficiently.

Comment: @Blorgbeard the solution is nice because it is elegant and easy to understand.  It isn't the most efficient solution, but it should be fast enough for most UI use cases and it is very easy to understand.

Comment: I was actually thinking something like `array.Select((x, i) => new { x, i }).OrderBy(p => p.x).Select((p, j) => new { p.i, j }).OrderBy(q => q.i).Select(q => q.j).ToArray()`